# Categorize nodes outside of create/update form

Tags: entities, nodes

I should add some new taxonomy reference fields to my Blog content type, but currently this content type has a lot of fields and a very complex UI.

I think it may help to let user categorize his post after inserting, outside of create and update forms.

Is there any module or configuration for this situation?

Comment: You might be able to simulate something using the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag)...

Comment: But my need is very similar to http://drupal.org/project/block_upload

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood